# Installing 1.9gazebo from source in local directory, error

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi
Hi Everyone,
I have tried to install 1.9Gazebo from source using local directory. Everything went well until the last step, "Setup enviroment variables" I follow the instructions below:

```
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PATH=<install_path>/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

And I got the following error:

```
bash: install_path: No such file or directory
```

Then when I run Gazebo ../path$ gazebo I got the error "command not found"
I am new on linux so I couldn't figure out yet how to fix this problem
This is the second time that installs Gazebo from source. The first time I successfully installed it using the default path (/usr/local) but I failed installing gazebo_ros_pack. This why I am reinstalling gazebo for the second time using local directory and see if I could successfully install gazebo_ros_packs .
Are there any differences-advantages of installing gazebo from source using the default path or local directory??
Thanks you for your help in this matter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6015/installing-1.9gazebo-from-source-in-local-directory,-error/) by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Well the

```
<install_path>
```

label was supposed to be replaced by your filesystem install path, typically by /usr.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on 2014-04-23**:
Thanks Jose!

**Comment by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on 2014-04-23**:
Jose, i made the changes and I realized that "make" creates for PKG_CONFIG_PATH the path ".../lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig" instead of  ".../lib/pkgconfig" which appears on the instructions. I am wondering if it will cause a problem or I might made a mistake somewhere during the process. Thanks a lot in advance for any input

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-04-25**:
That is a valid multiarch path, don't need to worry, should work just fine. Another point, could please mark the answer as valid by clicking the tick button? It helps me to know what answers are still waiting.